# Derivative of survival function under the integral sign.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory

Suppose $F$ is the distribution function of a continuous, nonnegative random variable $X$ with $\mathbb E[X]<\infty$ and let $\bar F=1-F$. I am interested in the quantity
$$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\left[\bar F(x)\int_x^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf du\right], \tag 1$$
which by the product rule is equal to 
$$\bar F(x)\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\int_x^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf du - f(x)\int_x^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf du $$
 but I am not sure how to compute
$$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\int_x^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf du. \tag 2$$
Is there a simple expression for $(2)$, or perhaps a more elegant way of computing $(1)$? Since $$\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf du $$ it seems we should have $$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\int_x^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf du = -\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\int_0^x \bar F(u)\ \mathsf d u =-\bar F(x),  $$
is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}F(x,u)du = F(b(x))\dfrac{db}{dx} -F(a(x))\dfrac{da}{dx} +\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x,u) du
$$
Setting $a(x) = x$ and $b=\text{const}$ and $F(x,u) = \bar{F}(u)$ we get
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}F(u)du  = -\bar{F}(x) 
$$
Note that I have not checked if your underlying logic makes sense.

Comment: That is what I am getting as well, so I suppose it is correct. Thanks!